# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Class out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, jackson

I can't understand propperly the error I get when I run this code:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);  
String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);  
JSONArray json = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);  
JSONObject metadatacontent = json.getJSONObject(0);   
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
mapper.readValue(metadatacontent.toString(), MetadataContentBean.class.getClass());
```

Error:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   Can not deserialize instance of
>   java.lang.Class out of START_OBJECT
>   token  at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@e3b895; line: 1,
>   column: 1]    at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:159)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:192)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer$ClassDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:439)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer$ClassDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:421)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1588)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1116)
>     at
>   com.path.parser.JSon.Parser(JSon.java:65)
>     at
>   com.path.parser.JSon.main(JSon.java:29)

What does it mean??

Maybe if I know this, I could find out my error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is the last line:

```
MetadataContentBean.class.getClass()
```

This means "get me the `Class` object for the MetadataContentBean class, and then get me the `Class` object for that `Class` object".... if you see what I mean. So you're asking Jackson to deserialize your JSON onto a `Class` object, which it doesn't know how to do.

This should be just

```
MetadataContentBean.class
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, but anyway I would like to know what is the meaning of the error!!
Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

This is probably related to the other question, but just to complete the answer, error comes from discrepancy: type "java.lang.Class" is serialized as a JSON String (class name itself), and not as JSON object like beans are. So deserializer expects to see a JSON String, instead sees a JSON Object (which starts with START_OBJECT) and throws exception.